# React Native API usage

Tags: json, typescript, react-native, rest

I want to display some data from our Solarpanels within an RN App. I have no experience with fetching the data from an json api like this, and the tutorials I found online is not working in this case for some reason.

Is there anyone who can take a look at this link, and point me in the right direction?
https://www.solaredge.com/sites/default/files/se_monitoring_api.pdf

When I open the API link with our API Key, I get something like this in the browser:

```
{"overview":{
"lastUpdateTime":"2022-02-14 13:57:00",
"lifeTimeData":{"energy":1.7024576E8},
"lastYearData":{"energy":8955.0},
"lastMonthData":{"energy":489.0},
"lastDayData":{"energy":0.0},
"currentPower":{"power":0.0},
"measuredBy":"INVERTER"}
}
```

I am using Ignite by Inifite Red as a boilerplate in this app, and there some builtin APISauce function I'm not familiar with if that makes it easier.

Answer (score 0):

Check import you are using of dependency which is not installed and package.json so that you have installed correctly the dependencies.